# (Python) Need help to break while loop after I got events in a row

Tags: python

Hello im really new to python and I managed to create a coin flip loop that spits out heads and tails.
What I know what to do is to break this loop after I've for example 10 heads in a row.

As you can see I have tried to break it after 10 heads but that just breaks it after 10 heads obviously not 10 heads in a row
Thank you!

```
import random

flips = 0
heads = 0
tails = 0

while flips < 500:
  if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
    print("heads")
    heads += 1 
  else:
    print("tails")
    tails += 1
  flips += 1
  if heads == 10:
    break

print("You got", heads, "And", tails, "Tails")
```

Comment: When you throw a tails, reset `heads` to zero. That way it can only get to ten if you get ten `heads` in a row.

Comment: Agree with @khelwood, and I add that if you need `heads`, you can create another variable to manipulate (like `heads_in_a_row`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to check if you got ten heads in a row, by resetting a counter (`heads_in_a_row`) to zero each time you throw tails.

```
import random

flips = 0
heads = 0
tails = 0
heads_in_a_row = 0

while flips < 500:
    if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
        print("heads")
        heads += 1 
        heads_in_a_row += 1
    else:
        print("tails")
        tails += 1
        heads_in_a_row = 0
    flips += 1
    if heads_in_a_row == 10:
        break

print("You got", heads, "heads and", tails, "tails")
```

You could also change your `while` condition to

```
while flips < 500 and heads_in_a_row < 10:
```

which arguably makes the logic a little clearer.